# How to add an actionListener as a separate class in java

Tags: java

I've been working on a program and my master class with the bulk of the code has over 20 different "addActionListener" methods. How can I instead create this actionListener, itemStateChanged etc etc in a separate class but still perform as it should the way it does now. Any tips would be most welcome as I have run over 4000 lines of code already in this class :( Thank you!

Comment: So, we're supposed to provide code that does the same thing as what your current code does, without knowing the current code? Where's your code? What have you tried? What were the problems faced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Mylistener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         if (e.getSource() == someButton){
             // do something
         } else if (e.getSource() == someOtherButton){
             // do something
         } 
         // add more else if statements for other components
         // e.getSource() is the component that fires the event e.g. someButton
    }
}
```

Say you have two buttons

```
JButton someButton = new JButton("SOME BUTTON");
JButton someOtherButton = new JButtton("SOME OTHER BUTTON");

ActionListener listener = new MyListener();

someButton.addActionListener(listener);
someOtherButton.addActionListener(listener);
```

**Edit:**

```
public MyClass extends JFrame {

    JButton someButton = new JButton("SOME BUTTON");
    JButton someOtherButton = new JButtton("SOME OTHER BUTTON");

    public MyClass(){

        ActionListener listener = new MyListener();
        someButton.addActionListener(listener);
        someOtherButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    class Mylistener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         if (e.getSource() == someButton){
             // do something
         } else if (e.getSource() == someOtherButton){
             // do something
         } 
         // add more else if statements for other components
         // e.getSource() is the component that fires the event e.g. someButton
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the OP's goal is to create a separate class. Therefore the class won't have a reference to all the button variables. When creating separate classes each ActionListener should only perform one function so you don't need to know the function, or if it is a common function across buttons then you use the getSource() method to know the component that generated the event.

Comment: That's right, so how can the new actionListener class execute the methods knowing that the variables are all in the master class? What do you mean by getSource() ?

Comment: Put the MyListener as an Inner class of your original class

Comment: Whichever component fires the event, is the `getSource()`. `e` is the event, so if `someButton` fires the event, then `e.getSource() == someButton`

Comment: @peeskillet your last edit is how i actually have it set up, which is the problem because i have a lot of these listeners which take up a large amount of lines and so I'd like to move each listener specific to a button into a new class. Each of these actionListeners uses a lot of different variables that were declared in the master class.

Comment: @Iron, then just leave out the if statements and put in your actionPerformed code.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // actionPerformed here...
    }
}
```

You would use it like:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());

// OR

MyActionListener listener = new MyActionListener();
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(listener);
```

Comment: Ok guys thank you all for the feedback. I will look into all the methods you've provided. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want to write a class which implements ActionListener.
I could give you some code here with very little explanation, but I think it is best that I point you to the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

This link will give you some examples, and it will explain in detail how it is working.
I hope this helps.